# Android: Toggle Button On: Show Fragment Off: Hide Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, togglebutton

I want to toggle button to show my fragment when it's clicked on and when I click it again to remove my fragment or hide it.
Basically ~ On: Show Off: Hide

```
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    Shower_fragment shower_fragment = new Shower_fragment();
    android.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.linear_shower, shower_fragment, "Shower");
    if(isChecked){
        fragmentTransaction.show(shower_fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }else{
        fragmentTransaction.hide(shower_fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works, this way it works. :D
~ Notice the new fragment object in the Else clause.

```
ToggleButton toggleButton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);
    toggleButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            Shower_fragment shower_fragment = new Shower_fragment();
            android.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

            if( null == fragmentManager){
                Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Null Fragment Manager", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;}

            if(isChecked){
                Toast.makeText(getApplication(),"If Clicked", LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .add(R.id.linear_shower, shower_fragment, "Shower")
                        .show(shower_fragment)
                        .commit();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Else Clicked", LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Shower_fragment shower_fragmentElse = (Shower_fragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("Shower");
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .hide(shower_fragmentElse)
                        .commit();
            }
        }
    });
```

By the way, where you put the Override method shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think your forgot to call getFragmentManager();

```
Override public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
{ 
  Shower_fragment shower_fragment = new Shower_fragment();
  FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();

  if(null == fm){return;}
  if(isChecked)
  { 
     fm.beginTransaction();
       .add(R.id.linear_shower, shower_fragment, "Shower");
       .show()
       .commit(); 
  }else
  {  

    fm.beginTransaction();
       .add(R.id.linear_shower, shower_fragment, "Shower");
       .hide()
       .commit(); 
  } 
}
```

Comment: I have fragment manager declared in the class and then initialized in my onCreate method, also you seem to have a problem in the "else" portion, it should be ft instead of fm for .hide().commit();
~ But, even that isn't working.